# PHP upload script fail

Tags: php, upload

Im using BluImp file uploader. Greate little script that I've used forever.

Now I have scoured there forum and cant find anything but after debugging, I believe it is more of a permissions/restrictions/settings problem.

Once the upload has appeared to have finished, an error is returned:

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

After debugging it is cause by any functions writing to the server, i.e. file_put_contents, move_upload_file....

The file is 1.47 mb

my additional ini alterations are

```
max_execution_time = 1600
max_input_time = 1600
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

Can anyone see anything that I dont?

regards

Also I forgot to add that it does not happen to all files just a few

Comment: start with a 10k file, does that work ?

Comment: Is this a PHP error? or a JS error?

Comment: @Dagon just uploaded a 1,567kb PDF

Comment: if you add print_r($_FILES); it will show you the error code of the issue. [Error Messages Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: Do you restrict by MIME type in your code? Since some files upload, perhaps the different types of files are giving you grief?

Comment: Just done another test. The file is actually being uploaded but straight after the upload a request for the filesize is being made [filesize()] and it is that that is causing the error (echo before and after proves this) any ideas?

Comment: also killed the script beforehand to make sure the path is the same as the new uploaded file `/home/user/public_html/themes/themename/images/media/110.jpg` which is correct...

Comment: $_FILES will contain the file size, you shouldn't need to use filesize()

Comment: Its not my script, but what I can see is that it uses it for  is testing the posted filesize against the uploaded filesize (but it doesn't get that far)

Comment: its the script you are editing, if you don't understand it you a are not going to get very far

Comment: I understand the script well, I have made many alterations through my time using it but I cannot for the life of me understand why it is terminating at this point and not triggering any of the inbuilt output errors.

Comment: arghhh, just tried the filesize on that path outside the upload scope and returns the size... 3111319